# Which programming languages work well together for simulations?

Tags: performance, simulation

Every programming language has advantages and disadvantages which make it more suitable to a specific solution. Sometimes it makes sense to combine the advantages of two (sometimes more) languages to solve the "bigger picture" problem in the most efficient manner (execution time vs programming time, etc.).

Some programming languages play better together than others because they are closely related in design, and some also provide better interfaces to other programming languages, which are not directly related.

I know it's impossible to list all the different combinations, but I'm interested in the interaction capability for simulation work between the most commonly used programming languages.

Typically there is a requirement for the following:

- Grunt work (fast as possible calculations) should support multi-threading
- Good code library support (e.g. math, statistics)
- User interface (e.g. simulation setup, plotting results)
- Operating system independence (Windows/Linux/Mac)

It's obviously *possible* to use any two languages together in some way or another, but I know there are instances where it definitely makes more sense to do so.

Comment: I'm not looking for a silver bullet solution...

Comment: Voting to close. Question does not have enough refined scope -- a (better) question might be: "Which languages work well as game-engine/game-script combination?" (Adjust as appropriate; in any case a refined scope could get better *concrete* replies).

Comment: What an absurd, worthless measurement that TIOBE index uses. A web search? *"The popular search engines Google, MSN, Yahoo!, Wikipedia and YouTube are used to calculate the ratings."* Also voting to close; I neither understand the question nor know how it's answerable.

Comment: Agreed, I should have made the question more specific.

Comment: @Keplerian: If you can think of a better way to phrase it, go ahead and edit your question. Even once it's closed, people can vote to reopen. But my *primary* issue is that I don't understand how the answer can be anything other than 1) arbitrary statistics never did anyone any good. Trying to "follow the leader" and choose the coolest language doesn't result in the best program. 2) any language(s) you want can work together, a la GolezTrol's answer.

Comment: Also, as you can see, MOST of the answers devolve to just listing some random set of things some developer is used to. Most of which are totally irrelevant coupling of a "random language/random language's templating framework/JS+HTML" that don't work any better together than some OTHER language. The only minor quibbling exception can be made for PHP which builds in the templating framework into the core language, though IMHO it doesn't really count for much.

Comment: @Keplerian - your update is much better, though I would strongly suggest you streamline it a bit and post as a brand new question. I would word it something like "Which programming languages can be chosen for implementing various subsystems of simulation system, with easy integration being a strong requirement"

Comment: Keplerian: I recommend you take a look at my project GarlicSim. Let me know if you need help with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost any scripting language (Perl, Python, Ruby, Lua, etc.) and C. You use the scripting language for rapid prototyping and then C to reimplement the slower parts.

C++ can also be used, but it has some features that are difficult to integrate as, for instance, virtual methods.

Then you have Jython, that's a version of Python running on top of the JVM that plays quite nicely with Java, and there are a bunch of other JVM languages in the same position.

If you use .Net or Mono, at least in theory, all the languages supported should be able to call code in other languages.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably change that to top 11, because JavaScript is invaluable when it comes to combining languages. Why? Because that's the only one you can run in a browser!

So, my answer is exactly that: Two languages that work well together are JavaScript and X (where X is any top 10 language from your list); JavaScript on the client, X on the server.

Comment: I agree, it does not have to be top 10. I intended to only use the 'top 10' badge as an example of a measure of programming language popularity.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very general, but basically, most Win32 languages can work together. You can write fast dll's in C++ and then use Visual Basic 6 to make slow calls to it. ;) Delphi and C++ work well together too, although there isn't much reason to use C++ dlls in Delphi because Delphi will perform just as well.

The same goes for .NET assemblies. All of them can work together, so you can write a framework in C#, while choosing a language with an easier syntax (like VB.NET or Prism) to allow beginning programmers (or those migrating from VB) to use that framework.

Answer (score 0):

C#/ASP.NET/JavaScript(jQuery/jQueryUI/jQueryMobile)

That pretty much sums up my life, haha

This is a very broad question, which will have far too many answers. Just because putting two languages together may be difficult for one person, it might be easy for another.

Comment: What specifically makes C#/ASP.NET/JS a special "works extra well" coupling compared to generic "Random language/That random language's web templating framework/JS"?

Answer (score 0):

For web design, 
HTML, CSS, JAVASCRIPT, JQUERY/YUI, PHP, MYSQL. Perfect blend. If you are just starting out, learn the languages in the order i have them listed.

Comment: First, learn to spell. It's not all capitalized. Second, HTML and CSS aren't languages; neither is jQuery/YUI (they are JavaScript frameworks/libraries). Neither is MySQL - it's a database server which uses a sub/superset of ANSI SQL as query language

Comment: Third, pretty much none of these systems (most of which aren't languages) "work well together" any better than any other ones, may be with exception of a rather dubios allegation that PHP works well with MySQL - there might be some internal language mechanics that make MySQL integration easier, but they are no better than database libraries frameworks in any other languages (e.g. DBI type stuff in Perl).

Comment: Ditto for HTML/CSS and PHP. If you add a proper templating HTML library to any language (JSPs for Java, Embper/HTML::Template to Perl, etc...), PHP all over the sudden stops having any special unique HTML-related features. Although I grant you, strictly speaking PHP's HTML templating stuff is built in into the core language, so it CAN be argued it's more tightly coupled - but definitely not to the point of "Perfect blend"

Comment: This is a very general questions. i'm answering from the web development point of view. @DVK, MYSQL being a query language, it's still a language that have to be learned. You also referred to it as a language in your post above.

Comment: no, you answered "Some programming languages play better together than others" question with listing some languages/systems **YOU know** as the only criteria for why they are "better than others" at playing together. Yes, they DO play together. Just not any better than others you don't know.